# Input CSS styles not working with runat server

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms

I'm working on updating checkbox inputs to use the styles from the US Web Design Standards. However, I've ran into an issue when trying to update the checkboxes in pages still within our .NET app that have the runat="server" attribute. 
Without the runat="server" attribute, the checkboxes render as in https://standards.usa.gov/components/form-controls/. With the runat="server" attribute, only the square outline renders and clicking on it does nothing - it doesn't change the background to blue, nor does it insert the checkmark svg.
Any help in understanding what is going on in order to make the styles work with runat="server" will be greatly appreciated.

This is the.NET code

```
<fieldset class="fieldsGroup standardFieldsGroup termsAndConditions" 
  runat="server" id="termsAndConditions">
  <legend><span class="uppercase small">Terms & Conditions</span></legend>
    <div class="formField fieldTypeCheckbox authorized">
      <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="idAuthorized" 
       name="authorized" class="authorized gs-input"/>
      <label for="idAuthorized" class="gs-input">I am authorized by this 
       organization to update the information on their Page
      </label>
      <span class="validators">
       <span id="idAuthorizedValidator" class="displayHidden">You must be 
        authorized to update the information on this organization's 
        Page Form</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="formField fieldTypeCheckbox acceptTerms">
      <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="idAcceptTerms" 
       name="acceptTerms" class="acceptTerms gs-input" />
      <label for="idAcceptTerms" class="gs-input">I agree to X's <a 
       id="aTermsAndConditions" href="https://x.org/terms-of-
       use" target="_blank" class="black-link underline">Terms and 
       Conditions</a>
      </label>
      <span class="validators">
        <span id="idAcceptTermsValidator" class="displayHidden">You must 
         agree to the X Terms and 
         Conditions
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
 </fieldset>
```

The following is the CSS

```
input.gs-input {
  //webkit-appearance: none;
  //-moz-appearance: none;
  //appearance: none;
  border: 0.1rem solid #5b616b;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #212121;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  height: 4.4rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  max-width: 46rem;
  padding: 1rem 0.7em;
  width: 100%;
}

label.gs-input {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}

input.gs-input[type="checkbox"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 2 */
}

input.gs-input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}

.lt-ie9 [type=checkbox], .lt-ie9
[type=radio] {
  border: 0;
  float: left;
  margin: 0.4em 0.4em 0 0;
  position: static;
  width: auto;
}

[type=checkbox] + label.gs-input {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0.65em;
}

[type=checkbox] + label.gs-input::before {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #757575;
  content: '\a0';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  margin-right: 0.6em;
  text-indent: 0.15em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
}

[type=checkbox]:checked + label.gs-input::before {
  background-color: #0071bc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #0071bc;
}

[type=checkbox]:checked + label.gs-input::before {
  background-image: url("../img/correct8.png");
  background-image: url("../img/correct8.svg");
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

[type=checkbox]:disabled + label.gs-input {
  color: #d6d7d9;
}

[type=checkbox]:focus + label.gs-input::before {
  outline: 2px dotted #aeb0b5;
  outline-offset: 3px;
}

[type=checkbox]:disabled + label.gs-input::before {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #aeb0b5;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: Is `ClientIDMode="Static"` set on the controls or web.config? Not sure if that's necessary any more.

Comment: @wazz It's set to ClientIDMode="AutoID" in the web.config file.

Comment: Fwiw, on that standards web page, the only image being loaded is `correct8.svg` (not .png). And I often delete `..` before directories and just use `/img`. It seems to work way more consistently...fwiw.

Comment: Just looked at ClientIDMode (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I think it would be worth trying `Static`. Static will render the id you use on the page, AutoID "concatenates the ID values of each parent naming container with the ID value of the control." ... edit ... although, i'm not sure how that would affect something like `[type=checkbox]:checked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit of research based on @wazz comment above regarding setting `ClientIdMode="Static"` in the web.config file. I did not want to affect the entire application, however; just the specific inputs. I came across this blog 
https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series

It mentioned that `clientIdMode="Static"` could be applied to individual elements. I modified the inputs as shown below and it solved my problem.

`<input type="checkbox" clientIdMode="Static" runat="server" id="idAuthorized" name="authorized" class="authorized"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not really an answer; have to post here so i can add an image.

I'm not having trouble with this, but it did take a while to deal with the checkboxes and labels being off the page.

I'm sure you've covered this but just in case, make sure you're accessing the right element. The checkbox is `left: -999em;` and the label is -30. I took those off just so i could see them and got this (after creating the image and putting it in the right place).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input. Setting `ClientIdMode ="Static"` solves the issue and the `::before` element becomes "clickable" and behaves as expected, but I'll have to check with the rest of my team to see if it won't cause any issues with the rest of the app. I switched back to `"AutoId"` and removed the `left: -999em` and got results similar to your image, however, only clicking on the now-visible checkbox would render the blue/white checkmark. Clicking on the `::before` element still does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be worth trying Static. Static will render the id you use on the page, AutoID "concatenates the ID values of each parent naming container with the ID value of the control."